# JQuery Cycle Image Icons for Prev/Next

Tags: jquery, css, image, cycle

I'm trying to find out how to replace the links 'Prev' and 'Next' with actual images (I would like to use small arrow icons).

```
$('#s2').cycle({ 
    fx:     'fade', 
    speed:  'fast', 
    timeout: 0, 
    next:   '#next2',    <-- use small PNG image instead? 
    prev:   '#prev2'     <-- use small PNG image instead?
});
```

I'm referring to the Malsup example here: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html. Is there a way to do this? Those next2, prev2 classes are classes I can style separately in CSS?

thanks
JM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next and previous links have IDs attached to them, not classes, so simply use those IDs to style your links.

```
a#prev2 {
    // some styles here
}

a#next2 {
    // some styles here
}
```